# LabVIEW: How to copy from one array to another array?

Tags: labview

I would like to deep copy one array to another array. What is the best way to do it ?

I have attempted this way and it seems to work. I would like to deep copy it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - This is not a free code service or something alike. Show your attempts and people will try to help. For more information about why I downvoted, please check the link.

Comment: An array of what? I've not yet come across a data type in LabVIEW where deep v shallow copying is an issue.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I'm sorry. I have the code uploaded now.

Comment: @nekomatic An array of integers. Does the code above make sense to you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're used to a different language where everything is done by reference, but **you don't need to do any of this in LabVIEW.** LabVIEW *automatically* copies data on a wire when necessary, but not when it isn't necessary.

The only thing your code is doing is creating an array with an extra dimension, because inside your loop you're building each scalar value into a 1D array with one element, then passing that array to an **indexing array terminal** which builds an array of the data that is wired to it - since you're passing a 1D array in, you get a 2D array out. However you could have got exactly the same result, if that's what you really wanted, by wiring your original array to a `Build Array` function then reshaping it from 1 x *n* to *n* x 1 using `Reshape Array`:

[image: VI snippet showing array reshape]

If you're worried about memory allocations, which *you shouldn't need to be unless your code is actually running out of memory or running too slowly*, you can see where LabVIEW will and won't make a copy by choosing `Tools > Profile > Show Buffer Allocations`. This adds a little black dot to any terminal, of one of the data types you select, where a new memory buffer has had to be allocated. If you do this for the code above you'll see that building an array from lower-dimensional data needs a new buffer, but reshaping an array doesn't.

If you have a very special case where you need to force LabVIEW not to allocate a buffer you can use an `In Place Element Structure`. But for the vast majority of programming you don't need to think about any of this: just let LabVIEW take care of it for you.

In the meantime I suggest you read the [tutorial on loops](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7588/en/).